# create Menu in wpf C# For Patient Mangem

Tags: c#, wpf, menu

I am Working in a small project Patient Management in WPF C#  and I want to create list for Patient(Like the list at the left of the picture [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zw76.png)). 
How I can do like it I don't know which tools I should use.
please Help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In C# a list of patients like you show in your picture could be defined as follows:

```
public class PatientItem
{
  public string FirstName { get; set; }
  public string LastName { get; set; }
  public string Gender { get; set; }
  public int Age { get; set; }
  public int VisitorId { get; set; }
  public string Diagnosis { get; set; }
  public string FileNamePicture { get; set; }
 }
```

A list of patients is defined as:

```
 List<PatientItem>
```

Next step would be to define your layout XAML and C#.

An example can be found at https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/list-controls/itemscontrol/

In that example, replace the TodoItem with PatientItem and change the bindings and the XAML, to update your layout from PatientItem instead of TodoItem.

To bind your picture there are several options, refer e.g. to answers here,

[Wpf: How to bind an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22635457/wpf-how-to-bind-an-image)

[How do I bind a WPF Image element to a PNG on the local hard drive using a relative filepath derived from a DB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17267021/how-do-i-bind-a-wpf-image-element-to-a-png-on-the-local-hard-drive-using-a-relat)